# AMS1117 3.3V regulator outputs 4.2V or 3.3V depent on source of 5V input

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm trying to use a AMS1117 3.3V to deliver 3.3V from a 5V input.

Case 1. 5v input supplied from 5V output of usb power supply module pictured below
[image: Image of usb power supply module]
Works like a charm, 5V in and 3.3V out.

Case 2. 5V input supplied directly from micro usb output.

When the voltage regulator is not attached, the micro usb outputs 5V. When it is attached, this output goes down to 4.9V and the regulator outputs 4.2V.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on? The 5V output from the module passes through a chip with an underlined 4 on it. What does this chip do?

edit: schematic added[image: schematic]

Comment: What equipment is the "micro usb output" in case 2 on?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it's literally just a female micro usb smd soldered to some circuit board. Like in the image link https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51fd8fU%2BGsL._AC_SL1100_.jpg

Comment: Need schematic for that PCB.

Comment: Hi Brian, the schematic for the micro usb? It's 5 pins with ground and 5V at the two ends. I've not connected any of the three data pins in the middle. Full details here https://www.sunrom.com/p/micro-usb-connector-b-female-5-pin-smd

Comment: The AMS1117 is a chip, you need to show how it is connected on the board: you must supply a schematic.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for clarifying. I've added a schematic

Comment: If you're getting too high an output voltage, you probably don't have a ground connection to the regulator, or else you bought the wrong version of the regulator.  If you're getting a sagging input, you're drawing power from something that is not a supply pin, or you are overloading it.  You may find like a lot easier if you use an old USB "A" cable as a captive input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it is defective, assuming you've connected and measured it correctly.

The part you mention is a self-resetting fuse (maybe 0.5A rating) and should have minimal voltage drop in normal operation.

Check that there is not an open solder joint on the AMS1117 leads (esp. the left-hand one).

Comment: Thanks, what I don't understand is how it can work with one 5V input and not with the other. I have a whole pack of the AMS1117s and I've tried 4 all with the same results.

Comment: Is anything other than a handheld battery-powered meter connected to the output (EITHER ground or 3.3V)?

Comment: No, just the meter. I've tried with and without capacitors between input and ground and output and ground as is recommended practice.

Comment: Maybe a pinout error of some kind on the micro USB, like  using pin 4 rather than pin 5?

Comment: Maybe, the micro usb still shows 5V on the voltmeter but I'm not sure what it would show if I'd caught the 4th pin, they're very small and my soldering iron is a bit chunky

Comment: Thanks everyone, it was a bad solder on the usb side, the ground pin was touching the next pin along. I ended up cutting the data pins back to make sure that they weren't in the way. Combination of Spehro and Chris' answers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, it was a bad solder on the usb side, the ground pin was touching the next pin along. I ended up cutting the data pins back to make sure that they weren't in the way.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/271590)

Comment: shnap - Hi, Instead of adding this as an answer, it should be added as a comment on the answer you kindly accepted from *Spehro*. That answer already explained the possibility of a solder joint problem, so your answer is confirming that - hence it's just showing that the accepted answer was correct.

Comment: Hi @SamGibson, I've left this in a comment under Spehro's response which I had already accepted as the answer. I think having the precise answer listed is useful to anyone searching for a solution to a similar problem but happy to delete it if it goes against the mod rules.